# Confirmation of form email receipt

Tags: cognito-forms

Can you have a completed form generate an email confirmation to the person filling it out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Yes, if you are collecting Email information in your form you can have a confirmation email sent to the end user who filled out the form. You can learn more about setting this up in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/13/building-forms/confirmation-emails).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did figure out how to turn this setting on. Your reward for your rapid and useful response will be a heightened sense of peacefulness at some point during the coming day.